# faking/simulating typing in Vim

Tags: vim

I am writing a very small script in VimL and I am looking to simulate actual typing of a given string.

The problem I am facing is that anything I try places the whole string instantly on the buffer, so the whole operation looks quite atomic and it doesn't portray the natural latency of char-by-char of typing.

I've tried a few variations of the function below, and even though I've added a `sleep 50m` at different places, I don't get the desired behavior:

```
function! FakeTyping(string)
    let list = split(a:string)
    for word in list
        for letter in split(word)
            execute "normal a" . letter . "\<esc>"
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction
```

Is this even possible? and if so, what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need. You hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>MiddleMouse</kbd> to send the content of clipboard to vim char by char:

```
nmap <C-MiddleMouse> :call AnimateText(@*)<CR>
fun! AnimateText(text)
    let lineno = line('.')
    let lines = split(a:text, "\n")
    for line in lines
        call setline(lineno, '')
        let chars = split(line, '.\zs')
        let words = ''
        for c in chars
            let words .= c
            call setline(lineno, words)
            call cursor(lineno, 0)
            normal z.
            if c !~ '\s'
                sleep 100m
                redraw
            endif
        endfor
        let lineno += 1
    endfor
endfun
```

Comment: I don't need the contents of the clipboard per se, as this is a small part of a bigger thing I am working on, but this is *spot on*. Thank you!

Comment: You can change the function name to `FakeTyping`, and try: `:call FakeTyping('hello, world')`